# Kotlin & flow & MVVM -> observer triggered multiple time when switch fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-flow

I'm learning flows and implementing them in my project, but I'm not sure I understood everything.

This is my model

```
data class ResultResponse (
    @field:Json(name = "count") val count : Int?,
    @field:Json(name = "favorites") val "favorites") : List<Favorite>?
)
```

This is my service

```
@GET("...")
suspend fun getFavorites(@Path("visitor") visitor: String) : Response<ApiModel<ResultResponse>>
```

This is my repository

```
suspend fun getFavorites(visitor: String) = flow {
    emit(apiCall { api.getFavorites(visitor) })
}.onStart {
    emit(State.loading())
}
```

Where apiCall is

```
suspend fun <T> apiCall(call: suspend () -> Response<T>): State<T>
```

This is my view model

```
private val parentJob = Job()

private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Default

private val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)

private val repository = FavoriteRepository(Api.favoriteService)

private val _favorites = MutableLiveData<State<ApiModel<ResultResponse>>>()

val favorites: LiveData<State<ApiModel<ResultResponse>>>
    get() = _favorites

fun fetchFavorites() {
    scope.launch {
        repository.getFavorites(Preferences.visitor).collect {
            _favorites.postValue(it)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    observer()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    favoriteViewModel.fetchFavorites()
}

private fun observer() {
    favoriteViewModel.favorites.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { state ->
        when (state) {
            is State.Loading -> doSomethingOnLoadingState()
            is State.Success -> doSomethingOnSuccessState(state)
            is State.Error -> doSomethingOnErrorState(state)
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is when I switch fragment and come back to this one, it observes again the last state, so I got State.Success then State.Loading then State.Success triggered. I tried to solve it using an [Event and getContentIfNotHandled()?](https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/5b661f1800e1e654f07cc54fe87441af) but it didn't change anything.

And the second question is did I do it right, is this the best way to do it currently?

Comment: `fetchFavorites()` triggered from `onResume()` and as expected every time

Comment: Yes I want to refresh the list each time the user opens the view. The first time works well, the second time I noticed that it called several times my observer (the precedent state + the new state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works as expected. After returning to the fragment, your LiveData still holds previous Success state, then gets another Loading and Success from repository.

For me, having a `loading` state in your repository doesn't seem right. I'd move it to ViewModel and then emit it only if necessary(if you actually want to show it in view), e.g. by checking current liveData state or by having a boolean flag in fetchFavourites method.

As for the second question - as always - it depends. I, personally wouldn't create a flow for a single api call, but would rather use a suspend function.

Comment: But I don't want to hold the previous state, because it's triggered two times my doSomethingOnSuccessState(state) function.